# Linq query returns a zero

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to search values according to a selected week from a datetime picker,from a datatable using following Linq queries.But It returns me only a 0.

Picking the date:

```
DateTime selecteddate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
int currentDayOfWeek = (int)selecteddate.DayOfWeek;
DateTime sunday = selecteddate.AddDays(-currentDayOfWeek);
DateTime monday = sunday.AddDays(1);
if (currentDayOfWeek == 0)
{
  monday = monday.AddDays(-7);
}
List<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
            .Select(days => monday.AddDays(days))
            .ToList();
```

My LINQ query as follows.

```
var sumIncomes = dataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r["Type"]?.ToString() == "Income" && 
                dates.Contains((DateTime)r["Date"]))
    .Sum(rs => (decimal)rs["Amount"]);

var sumExpenses = dataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r["Type"]?.ToString() == "Expense" && 
                dates.Contains((DateTime)r["Date"]))
    .Sum(rs => (decimal)rs["Amount"]);
```

My data table looks like this.

[image]

I'm not sure what causing this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting the Values according to selected weeks. But it only gives a zero.

Comment: Case sensitive maybe. Try using "type" instead of "Type".

Comment: The `.ToString()` will not work I think. It will use the `.ToString()` of the `Object` type which results in a description of the object. Try a `(string)` cast instead.

Comment: And what date are you actually selecting in your control?

Comment: By the way, if you're going to use LINQ to DataSet then you should use it, i.e. `Where(r => r.Field<string>("Type") == "Income" && dates.Contains(r.Field<DateTime>("Date")))` and `Sum(rs => rs.Field<decimal>("Amount"))`.

Comment: case may be a problem. Just try with smaller Where clause first.

Comment: I edited 'object1' to 'sumIncomes', etc. Perhaps the 'var' could be more specific, probably 'int'. Logical meaningful names will reduce complexity, saving neurons for solving the bug.

Comment: If you replace the Where condition to an actual function, it is easier to inspect with the debugger which part is not working right, e.g. because of case

Comment: For proper date comparison you could add `.Date` to each DateTime variable

Comment: dates.Contains might by an issue concerning TimeZone and DateTimeKind. Both comparands should be normalized to UTC and DateOnly portions.

Answer (score 0):

I created table like yours and here is what I found, your LINQ expression missing some things.

```
List<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                        .Select(days => monday.AddDays(days))
                        .ToList();

               dates.Add(new DateTime(2021, 5, 10)); //add for simplicity to match one record from your table didn't have time to create win form project

var sumIncomes = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Type").Trim() == "Income" && 
                                      dates.Contains(r.Field<DateTime>("Date")))
                          .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount"));
```

As user @user18387401 noted you should use Field extension method provided with column type in this case string. When you insert data in your table if column type is nvarchar(10) you will have data in column like this "Income    " not like this "Income" so you always need to trim string value from database.

```
r.Field<string>("Type").Trim()
```

Second issue you have in Sum method (decimal)rs["Amount"] on this line program will throw runtime exception "Invalid cast" because you have int column for Amount and here you try to cast in decimal, you should provide correct type in Field method.

```
r.Field<int>("Amount")
```

Hope this helps and works for you.